# Cannot find module 'node-sass' while running the angular 7 application

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I am trying to run my application but I am getting the below error.

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
>           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\App\xxxx\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
>   ERROR in ./src/app/widget-modules/xxxxx/xxxx.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './xxxxx.component.scss' in 'C:\Users\oooo\mmmm\App\zzzz\src\app\yyyy\xxxx'.

I tried installing node-sass with below commands but nothing's working. I am also getting the python error when I try to run below commands.

```
    npm i node-sass
    npm i --save node-sass
    npm i --save-dev node-sass
    npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Error:

> can't find python executable python you can set the python env variable.

Also I deleted the node_modules folder and reinstalled but not working.

Comment: Have you tried removing node_modules and re-run npm install?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Yes I did and it didn't work

Comment: Hmm, maybe this one: `npm rebuild node-sass --force`?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek just tried and same error :(

Comment: In the commands you provided you got a typo: `npm i --save-dev node sass` <-- missing `-` between *node* and *sass*. Is it copy-paste issue?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek yes, it is a typo. Thanks for pointing out! I have corrected it.

Comment: As I see you runing under windows. node-sass for windows requires node-gyp to compile. Try to run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` then `npm i node-sass`

Comment: @Dimanoid I tried but I am getting below error. _Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.36.223:443
Downloading Python failed. Error: { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT_

Comment: Well then you have problems with your internet connection...

Comment: I tried to run this `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` command in my project folder.

Comment: @Dimanoid Internet connection is working fine. I don't have admin rights and it maybe the problem?

Comment: Probably, windows-build-tools installs globally so you may need enough access right for that. Try to search how to configure node/npm to use separate folder for global packages.

Comment: what is your node version?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late answer, but it may be help for some one in future

The same problem ,I faced.In my case, I installed `npm` by using force with below command

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: After struggling to fix it for entire day, this post helped me counter this issue. God bless u brother.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your version of node.js.
2. Make sure you uninstall global version of node_sass (if you have installed previously)
3. If its < 10 or v. 12 please install node v.10 with lts support.

That should fix your issue.

Answer (score -2):

I know its too late to answer this question but I found perfect solution of this issue.

You need to check your node version and according install node-sass
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass
Suppose your version is v13.14.0 (in cmd type node -v )
then install 4.13 node-sass version (npm i node-sass@4.13)

Comment: NOT CLEAR AT ALL.